# Luhn Credit Card Validation in Java

Tags: java

Looking for help with my java program that uses Luhn Algorithm to validate a credit card number entered by the user. The card number must be between 13 and 16 digits in length, start with either a 4 (for Visa), 5 (Master card), 37(Amex), or a 6 ( Discover). Program should take input as a long and display if the input is valid or invalid. This is what I have so far, Excuse the formatting.

Even when I enter a valid card number, It is printing that it is invalid and I do not know why. Also unsure how to specify the parameters of the length of the card since it must be between 13-16 characters to be valid.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lunh {

  public static void main(String []args){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      long cardNumber;
      int sum = 0;
     boolean even = false;

      String cardType;
      System.out.println("Enter credit card number"); //prompt user to enter their card number
      cardNumber = input.nextLong();

      String cardNumberString = Long.toString(cardNumber); //card number entered as a long and converted to string 
      isValid(cardNumberString);
  }
    public static boolean isValid(String cardNumber){
    int sum = 0 ;
    boolean even = false;
    String  cardType = null;

    int firstDigit = getDigit(cardNumber,1);
    switch (firstDigit){
        case 4: 
        cardType = "Visa";
        break;
        case 3:
        if (getDigit(cardNumber,2)==7) {
            cardType= "American Express";
            } else {
            return false;
            }
        case 5:
        cardType = "Master Card";
        break;
        case 6: 
        cardType = "Discover";
        break;
    } //end card type switch

    int secondDigit = getDigit(cardNumber, 2);

    //loops through digits in reverse order right to left
    for (int i = cardNumber.length();i>0; i--){
        int digit = getDigit(cardNumber, i);

        //double every other digit
        if (even)
        digit += digit;

        even = ! even;

        //if result is greater than 9 then subtract 9
        if (digit > 9)
        digit = digit - 9;

        sum += digit;
        } //end of loop

    if (sum % 10 == 0) 
    {
        System.out.println(cardNumber+" is valid");
        System.out.println("Card Type: "+cardType);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(cardNumber+ " is invalid");
        System.out.println("Card Type: Invalid");
        return false;
    }
    } //end of isValid class

    //gets digit at specified position
    private static int getDigit(String digitString, int position){
        String characterAtPosition = digitString.substring(position - 1, position);
        return Integer.parseInt(characterAtPosition);
    }  
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: You should try listing a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't understand the algo. See also [Luhn_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)

The right most digit of the input is the check digit. You have to start your computation (sum, which seems basically correct) from the second last digit. The sum is then multiplied by 9 modulo 10:

```
computedCheckDigit = sum*9%10
```

This value is compared aginst the right most digit of your input. If it is equal the Luhn-Check is valid.